# What does the link rel="index" thing do?

Tags: html, hyperlink, seo

Like this:

```
<link rel='index' title='mysite' href='http://mysite.com/' />
```

It appears inside all pages of the website.

I hope it doesn't tell google not to index that page :|

Also there's a

```
<link rel='canonical' title='mysite' href='http://mysite.com/' />
```

What is that for?

Answer (score 8):

> `<link rel='index' title='mysite' href='http://mysite.com/' />`

It states that the linked document [provides an index](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-links) for the current document … which probably isn't true.

> `<link rel='canonical' title='mysite' href='http://mysite.com/' />`

It states that `http://mysite.com/` is the same page as the current document, and that the proper URL to use is `http://mysite.com/`.

Comment: hmmm does that index always have to be my homepage?

Comment: No. As I commented, that usage seems to be wrong. [this is a good example of an index](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/list.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `rel` attribute on the `link` element just says "there is this other document, whose url is the value of the `href` attribute, that is related to the current document.

There are many kinds of values used for `rel`, the most common of which is `stylesheet`.  In the case of `"index"` it means this other document somehow indexes this document.

There is a list of common rel values, on of all places, w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_link_rel.asp).  (I'm not a fan of w3schools but I thought you might like to see the list of rel values they provided.)

Here is information on Google and rel=canonical: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394